# Duplicates in loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Please help me figure this one out as I am completely new to PHP and defiantly not going to win any trophies in coding efficiency.

I am pulling my CastingCartTalentID from WordPress and then using that ID to look up a category in another table in WordPress.
All CastingCartTalentID's are returned just fine, but since my Categories are being looked up within the nested foreach loop, I end up with duplicated Categories:-(
The Categories are finally assigned to buttons in HTML, but I don't want to have duplicated buttons on the page.

```
$myTalentID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT CastingCartTalentID FROM ".    table_agency_castingcart ." WHERE CastingJobID = '$mycustomID'");
foreach ($myTalentID as $obj){
$myID = $obj->CastingCartTalentID;
$mySort = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT B1.ProfileCustomValue FROM ". table_agency_customfield_mux ." B1, ". table_agency_customfields ." A1 WHERE B1.ProfileID = '$myID' AND A1.ProfileCustomTitle = 'Category' AND A1.ProfileCustomID = B1.ProfileCustomID");
foreach ($mySort as $obj){
$myCat = $obj->ProfileCustomValue;
echo "<td><button class=\"filter\" data-filter=\".category-    $myCat\">$myCat</button></td>";
}}
```

When I print_r my $mySort I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProfileCustomValue] => B ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProfileCustomValue] => A ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProfileCustomValue] => C ) )
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProfileCustomValue] => B ) )
```

I have tried using array_unique but that dosnt help me. Is there another way to solve this? or is there a solution to remove duplicates?

Please any help is appreciated

Comment: Obviously just add `distinct` to the first query too: `SELECT distinct CastingCartTalentID FROM ...`

Comment: That wouldn't help since I need the Categories for each TalentID

Comment: You haven't described the problem well.  Instead of those `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ProfileCustomValue] => B ) )` type prints, why not show the generated HTML you're expecting vs what you're getting, because it looks like from what you provided you're only using one variable...

Comment: Sorry, My Expected result would be to have no duplicated values in my array:



Don't want "B" to show up twice or any other duplicated value